# Can not save method in class when load model in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm save trying to save a custom model in Tensorflow 2.0. I followed the guide from Tensorflow.

Create a class model:

```py
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_units):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense_layers = [keras.layers.Dense(u) for u in hidden_units]

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs
        for layer in self.dense_layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x
    
    def get_layer_size(self):
        return len(self.dense_layers)
```

I added a method `get_layer_size` to return length of layers.
When I save and load model.

```py
model = CustomModel([16, 16, 10])
# Build the model by calling it
input_arr = tf.random.uniform((1, 5))
outputs = model(input_arr)
# model.save("my_model1")
keras.models.save_model(model, filepath="model_1")

# Delete the custom-defined model class to ensure that the loader does not have
# access to it.
del CustomModel

loaded = keras.models.load_model("model_1")
np.testing.assert_allclose(loaded(input_arr), outputs)

print("Original model:", model)
print("Loaded model:", loaded)
```

The problem when I call the `get_layer_size` method.

The original model: `model.get_layer_size()` return 3. However, `loaded.get_layer_size()` return error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 loaded.get_layer_size()
>
> AttributeError: 'CustomModel' object has no attribute 'get_layer_size'

Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14k4ehLdd_Yb-g8x9W3ZB9YLdJGcbIdMv?usp=sharing

How do I solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Have anyone help me? :(